# If $u\in F$ is Transcendental over $K$, $F$ an extension field of $K$, Show every element in $K(u)$ not in $K$ is transcendental over $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

Doing some problems out of Beachy’s Algebra text, I came across that problem, and I’m at a loss how to show it without a bit of hand waving. Do I make some statement about spaces, and prove by contradiction?

Ie. Suppose there exists an element $v\in K(u): v\not \in K$, such that $\exists$ minimal $ q(x)\in F[x], s.t. q(v)=0$. Since $v\notin K$, $v$ may be expressed as the linear combination of $au+b$, where $b$ is some element in $K$, and $a\ne 0$. Then the minimal polynomial in $K(u)$ has form: $q(t)=(t-v)=(t-(au+b)u),$ and $K(v)=(v-v)=0$.

This feels like possibly too much work or too little rigor for a relatively simple question, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry, is $F = K(u)$?

Comment: $F$ doesn't need to be $K(u)$ for the statement to be true.

Comment: If you're going through with a proof by contradiction you might want to show that if you have a polynomial $f \in K[x]$ with $f(au + b) = 0$ then you have a polynomial $g \in K[x]$ with g(u) = 0

Comment: Why does $v = au + b$?  Not seeing it.  Why can't $v = p(u)$, $p(x) \in K[x]$, $\deg p(x) \ge 2$?

Comment: u and b form a basis for K(u) over K since it is a simple extension.

Comment: @Boots  This isn't correct if you're talking about viewing $K(u)$ as a vector field over $K$.  Viewed as a vector field, $K(u)$ is infinite-dimensional over $K$, as demonstrated by the $K$-linearly independent set $\{u^k~|~k \in \Bbb Z \}$.

Comment: Ah yes you are right here, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac {m(u)}{d(u)}$ solves a polynomial of degree $n, p(x) \in K[x]$, then multiply through by $d(u)^n$ to find a polynomial in $K[x]$ with $u$ as a root, contradicting the assumption that $u$ is transcendental over $K$.

Comment: I don't understand but the underlying idea is looking correct. What do you mean that fraction solves a polynomial of degree n?

Comment: $p(\frac{m(u)}{d(u)})=\sum_{k=0}^na_k(\frac{m(u)}{d(u)})^k=0$ for some $a_k \in K$.

Comment: And how are we guaranteed that $\frac{m(u)}{d(u)}$ solves a polynomial in $K[x]$?

Comment: @Boots  We're assuming toward a contradiction that $\frac{m(u)}{d(u)}$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: So everything in K(u) not in K can be written in this form?

Comment: Yes.  That's pretty much the definition of $K(u)$ -- rational functions of $u$ with coefficients in $K$.

Comment: Oh yes, duh. I understand now thank you.